# Accessing AWS s3 buckets from an API and calling this API from another API C#

Tags: api, file, http, amazon-s3, .net-core

I have an API  `public async Task<IActionResult> GetS3DocumentDetails(int Id)`, this API basically retrieves the documents present in s3 bucket on the basis of an ID which I am passing , the code is like this,

```
  List<Stream> files = new List<Stream>();
    response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
                    foreach (var entry in response.S3Objects)
                    {
                        var pathCheck = Path.GetExtension(entry.Key).ToLower();
                        if (pathCheck != ".json")
                        {
                            var s3Object = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(
                                entry.BucketName,
                                entry.Key
                            );
                            var responseData = s3Object.ResponseStream;

                            files.Add(responseData);
                        }
                    }
                    request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
```

Now I am returning this List in a mutipartcontent like this

```
var multipartContent = new MultipartContent();

    foreach (var stream in response)
    {
           var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
           multipartContent.Add(streamContent);
    }

    `var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = multipartContent
    };

    return Ok(httpResponse);
```

I can see the count of files under httpResponse -> content-> _nestedContent
now this API `public async Task<IActionResult> GetS3DocumentDetails()` is getting called from another api like

```
 client.GetAsync($"http:RequestUrlPath/GetS3DocumentDetails?Id={Id}")

                using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    while (responseStream.Position<responseStream.Length)
                    {
                        var stream = new MemoryStream();
                        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        streams.Add(stream);
                    }
                }
```

but the problem is I cant see this stream details in the API which is getting called, what are the changes I can make to make this work  or is there any other  approach i can use

My end goal is basically to retrieve the documents which are present in the s3 bucket from an api and this API which is retrieving these details is getting called from another api which will take these data and process it in our image store,
Note : I am using .Net 6